# Calling a function in wp-includes/xxx.php to a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently doing a basic plugin.

I have created a php file containting a class and a private function inside the class.

How can I call a function from a file in wp-includes folder into the private function of the plugin.

example:

```
 class A{ 
    private function B{
    "call a function here from wp-includes/xxx.php "
    }
    }
```

Then I can call Class A from main.php of the plugin.

Thanx for any response.

Comment: I am not quite sure which direction you are looking after. Do you want to call a function *from* your plugin or *from* another file? If you are inside the wp framework, the function is most likely available anyway. If not, `include_once()` the file and call the functions needed.

Comment: where should I put the `include_once()` ?. before the `Class A` or inside the `private function B` or in the main.php?

Comment: Kindly answer the direction question first.

Comment: I want to call a function from another file inside wp-includes path to my plugin.

Comment: In that case use an `include()` statement before your `class` statement and the functions will be available.

Answer (score 0):

1. wp-includes/xxx.php must be included in your script
2. In your class method B just call the function like `your_function()` 
   or more correctly: `if function_exists('your_function') {your_function()}`

I'm not familiar with wordpress architecture, so I can't tell where you should use `require_once()`. In any case you can use `require_once()` right in B method of class A.